# How to display number of specific items in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, class

Let's say I have a class called `items` with this code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class items {
    private ArrayList<Item> itemlistweapons = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ArrayList<Item> itemlistapparel = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ArrayList<Item> itemlistaid = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ArrayList<Item> itemlistmisc = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public void additem(String name, String type){
        if("Weapon".equals(type)){
            itemlistweapons.add(new Item(name, type));
        }
        else if ("Apparel".equals(type)){
            itemlistapparel.add(new Item(name, type));
        }
        else if ("Aid".equals(type)){
            itemlistaid.add(new Item(name, type));
        }
        else if ("Misc.".equals(type)){
            itemlistmisc.add(new Item(name, type));
        }
    }

    public void dropitem(String name){
        for(int i = 0; i < itemlistweapons.size(); i++){
            if(itemlistweapons.get(i).getname().equals(name)){
                itemlistweapons.remove(i);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < itemlistapparel.size(); i++){
            if(itemlistapparel.get(i).getname().equals(name)){
                itemlistapparel.remove(i);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < itemlistaid.size(); i++){
            if(itemlistaid.get(i).getname().equals(name)){
                itemlistaid.remove(i);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < itemlistmisc.size(); i++){
            if(itemlistmisc.get(i).getname().equals(name)){
                itemlistmisc.remove(i);
            }
        }
        }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String items = "";
        if (itemlistweapons.size() > 0){
            items += "Weapons\n";
        for (Item itemlist1 : itemlistweapons) {
            items += itemlist1 + "\n";
        }
        }

        if (itemlistapparel.size() > 0){
            items += "Apparel\n";
        for (Item itemlist2 : itemlistapparel) {
            items += itemlist2 + "\n";
        }
        }
        if (itemlistaid.size() > 0){
            items += "Aid\n";
        for (Item itemlist3 : itemlistaid) {
            items += itemlist3 + "\n";
        }
        }
        if (itemlistmisc.size() > 0){
            items += "Misc.\n";
        for (Item itemlist4 : itemlistmisc) {
            items += itemlist4 + "\n";
        }
        }
        return items;
    }

}
```

I want to be able to display the number of specific items in that list.

For example, let's say, for my text based rpg game, the player adds 25 gold pieces to his inventory. I don't want it to display the word 'Gold' 25 times in his inventory, but rather 'Gold (25)' instead. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I see two ways you could do this. One way would be to include a method that counts how many times a given item occurs in each list, then display each item name once alongside its quantity. Another way would be to modify your Item class to include quantity as well as name and type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather confused by your question... But here goes nothing...

The [size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) method should give you what you're looking for. It's a part of the Collection interface, which ArrayList implements.

From the JavaDoc:

> int size()
>
> Returns the number of elements in this list. If this list contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

That being said, the following code demonstrates how you might use this method in practice:

```
List<GoldCoin> gold = new ArrayList<GoldCoin>();
// Code ...
System.out.println("Gold (" + gold.size() + ")");
```

However, it appears that you've already used this method in your above code sample... So I'm not sure whether or not this is actually what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of items in an arraylist for example the number of weapons you have you can simply use `itemlistweapons.size()` if you want to count some specific weapons like how many swords you have, you can increment a variable if the current weapon is a sword, while looping through itemlistweapons. For something like gold you don't want to use an arraylist, since a variable is enough, what you can increase whenever you get some gold.